# What is the relation between number of WiFi antenna and number of spatial streams?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, antenna, 802.11

As far as I know, 802.11n WiFi uses MIMO to increase throughput. It uses multiple Tx and Rx antenna (at both the AP and the client side) to send multiple spatial streams at the same time.

The number of antenna should be related to the number of spatial streams. For example, AP = 11n,2X2, laptop = 11n,2X2, and the connection supports 2 spatial streams.

However, I found that many products in the market do not follow this rule. For example:

1. [This product](http://www.shoppingsquare.com.au/p_402927_300Mbps_USB_Wireless_N_WiFi_Adapter_Dongle_80211_bgn_5dBi__Antenna_Genuine_W5) supports 2 streams but uses 1 antenna.
2. [This product](http://www.ampedwireless.com/products/rta15.html#product_specs) supports 2 streams but uses 3 antenna.
3. [This product](http://www.ncixus.com/products/?sku=85868) supports 3 streams but uses 5 antenna.
4. [This product](http://www.dlinkmea.com/site/index.php/site/productDetails/197) supports 1 stream but uses 2 antenna.

What is the relation between number of WiFi antenna and number of spatial streams?

If there is a relation between number of WiFi antenna and number of spatial streams, how can we apply that concept to WiFi Yagi antenna and WiFi grid parabolic antenna?

Comment: In an antenna array like a Yagi, the elements are acting coherently. They're not independent of one another. You don't transmit one signal through one element and an unrelated signal simultaneously through another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least as much antennae as you have streams. Besides, even with single stream more antennae can help in case of poor signal/noise ratio.

Regarding your examples:

1. Probably typo in description.
2. One dual band antenna + one 2.4GHz + one 5GHz; so up to two antennae for each band
3. 2 antennae for 2.4GHz band and 3 for 5GHz.
4. Professional/enterprise solution, more antennae for better signal.

Comment: How about [this product](http://www.dracotek.com/802-11n-300mbps-high-speed-wireless-wifi-usb-adapter-with-antenna-300nz.html), [this product](http://www.dx.com/p/edup-ep-ms1537-100mw-2-4ghz-300mbps-802-11b-g-n-usb-wlan-wi-fi-wireless-network-adapter-158558#.U9zO5eOSzqg), and [this product](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/300Mbps-USB-Wireless-Adapter-WiFi-Lan-Network-Card-Free-Shipping/497757613.html?)?

Comment: All of them are 1T2R: one transmitting antenna, 2 receiving, which means 150Mbit upstream, 300Mbit downstream.

Comment: You may need to make some correction in your answer. I think no.1 is not a typo error. Maybe there is a second, internal, antenna printed on the PCB board. You can refer to [this page](http://www.rowetel.com/blog/?p=673). It says "Even routers with just one visible external antenna may have a second, internal, antenna etched on the router PCB".